# OMAP Bootloader project query

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, boot, beagleboard, omap

In the below link, under kernel, it is mentioned that it "decompresses kernel image into SDRAM". Does u-boot do this ? If not how does 'kernel' decompress 'kernel' image ?

Link: http://omappedia.org/wiki/Bootloader_Project#OMAP_Bootloader_Overview

Comment: Kernel is indeed has a compressed body. The decompression is done in the first stage after bootloader transferred a control.